# Draw part of CGImage

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, cgimage

I have an application that draws images from a CGImage.

The CImage itself is loaded using a CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex to create an image from a PNG file.

This forms part of a sprite engine - there are multiple sprite images on a single PNG file, so each sprite has a CGRect defining where it is found on the CGImage.

The problem is, CGContextDraw only takes a destination rect - and stretches the source CGImage to fill it.

So, to draw each sprite image we need to create multiple CGImages from the original source, using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect().

I thought at first that this would be a 'cheap' operation - it doesn't seem necessary for each CGImage to contain its own copy of the images bits - however, profiling has revealed that using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect() is a rather expensive operation.

Is there a more optimal method to draw a sub-section of a CGImage onto a CGContext so I dont need to CGImageCreateWithImageInRect() so often?

---

Given the lack of a source rectangle, and the ease of making a CGImage from a rect on a CGImage I began to suspect that perhaps CGImage implemented a copy-on-write semantic where a CGImage made from a CGImage would refer to a sub-rect of the same physical bits as the parent.
Profiling seems to prove this wrong :/

Answer (score 3):

I was in the same boat as you. `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()` worked better for my needs but previously I had attempted to convert to an `NSImage`, and prior to that I was clipping the context I was drawing in, and translating so that `CGContextDrawImage()` would draw the right data into the clipped region.

Of all of the solutions I tried:

1. Clipping and translating was prohibitively tolling on the CPU. It was too slow. It seemed that increasing the amount of bitmap data only slightly made significant performance impacts, suggesting that this approach lacks any sort of scalability.
2. Conversion to `NSImage` was relatively efficient, at least for the data we were using. There didn't seem to be any duplication of bitmap data that I could see, which was mostly what I was afraid of going from one image object to another.
3. At one point I converted to a `CIImage`, as this class also allows drawing subregions of the image. This seemed to be slower than converting to `NSImage`, but did offer me the chance to fiddle around with the bitmap by passing through some of the Core Image filters.
4. Using `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()` was the fastest of the lot; maybe this has been optimised since you had last used it. The [documentation for this function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html) says the resulting image retains a reference to the original image, this seems to agree with what you had assumed regarding copy-on-write semantics. In my benchmarks, there appears to be no duplication of data but maybe I'm reading the results wrong. We went with this method because it was not only the fastest but it seemed like a more “clean” approach, keeping the whole process in one framework.

Answer (score 0):

[Create an NSImage with the CGImage](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/initWithCGImage:size:). An NSImage object makes it easy to [draw only some section of it to a destination rectangle](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:).

Comment: it would be ironic if the api i was avoiding as 'inefficient' turned out to bemroe capable and faster.

Comment: CGImage is better for some things, especially reading and writing raster images (with Image I/O). But NSImage is better for some things, too, like resolution-independent drawing (since an NSImage has a size in points to go with its representations' sizes in pixels). There's no single best-at-everything image class on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the recommendation is to use a clipping region.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when writing a simple 2D tile-based game.

The only way I got decent performance was to:

1) Pre-render the tilesheet CGImage into a CGBitmapContext using CGContextDrawImage()

2) Create another CGBitmapContext as an offscreen rendering buffer, with the same size as the UIView I was drawing in, and same pixel format as the context from (1).

3) Write my own fast blit routine that would copy a region (CGRect) of pixels from the bitmap context created in (1) to the bitmap context created in (2). This is pretty easy: just simple memory copying (and some extra per-pixel operations to do alpha blending if needed), keeping in mind that the rasters are in reverse order in the buffer (the last row of pixels in the image is at the beginning of the buffer).

4) Once a frame had been drawn, draw the offscreen buffer in the view using CGContextDrawImage().

As far as I could tell, every time you call CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(), it decodes the entire PNG file into a raw bitmap, then copies the desired region of the bitmap to the destination context.